# Custom error message not working in gorm with grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Can't seem to get custom validation messages working on Grails 2.3.7.

```
class Team {
   int id
   String email

   static mapping = {
     id     column:'TEAM_ID', generator:'native'
     email  column:'TEAM_EMAIL' 
   }
   static constraints = { 
     email  unique:true
   }
```

**messages.properties** (tried all of these...)

```
team.email.unique=Email already used!
Team.email.unique=Email already used!
my.package.Team.email.unique=Email already used!
```

Validation problems are picked up by my service, but the custom error message is never used:

```
Team t = new Team(...)
if(!t.validate())
   println t.errors
```

outputs...

```
Field error in object 'Team' on field 'email': rejected value.... ...
default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] with value [{2}] must be unique]
```

Not sure what's the issue, according to [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/validation.html) the convention is:

`[Class Name].[Property Name].[Constraint Code]`

### Extra Configuration

#### BuildConfig

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0')
}
plugins {
    build ":tomcat:7.0.52.1"
    runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.9"
}
```

### DataSource

```
 dialect  =  "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
 hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = false
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
    singleSession = false 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `className.propertyName.unique` according to the unique constraint doc page at http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/ref/Constraints/unique.html but `println t.errors` will always look like what you're seeing - the `toString()` result isn't very useful. To see resolved/translated messages you can test what you're doing in a test or test app, and you can use this to display the resolved messages:

```
// dependency injection in controller/service/etc.
def messageSource

...

Locale locale = Locale.getDefault()
def stringsByField = [:].withDefault { [] }

for (fieldErrors in t.errors) {
   for (error in fieldErrors.allErrors) {
      String message = messageSource.getMessage(error, locale)
      stringsByField[error.field] << message
   }
}

println stringsByField
```

Comment: What's messageSource? Is that a predefined  bean?

Comment: Yes, so you need to dependency-inject it as a class-scope variable in an artifact (controller, service, etc.)

Comment: It works, +1 for `MapWithDefault`, but `messageSource.getMessage(error, locale)` takes 2-3 seconds to respond, even on repeated invocations for the same error condition. I'm using a simple test app with minimal resources, just one domain class and service; I've updated my question with additional data; any ideas on why that call takes so long?

Comment: No idea, that should be pretty quick. This is the same bean used by Grails to display messages in GSPs - do you see similar slowness there?Note that it will be faster in production because it aggressively caches, whereas reloading is supported in dev mode (although it only reloads the source files when a change is detected or triggered manually).